# Intersect two List<int> having repeated values

Tags: c#

I have two lists of type int:

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int> {12,55,55,55,34};
List<int> list2 = new List<int> {12,55};
```

If I intersect list1 with list2, then the expected result is `{12,55,55,55}`.

How can I achieve this? Is there any other mean of achieving the same result?

Comment: @GrantWinney typically in .NET an intersection only includes/excludes elements in the first set, it does not concatenate sets.

Comment: @GrantWinney First list contains field IDs based on which I create controls dynamically. The field ID 55 represents space(blank textblock) which I need to create repetitively between unique common controls(field id 12) which are taken from second list. Since second list represent common field ids.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<int> result = list1.Where(i => list2.Contains(i)).ToList();
```

What this does is selects only the records in `list1` which exist in `list2`, which will result in an `IEnumerable<int>`. Then, the `ToList()` turns it back into a `List<int>`

The optimal version of this performance-wise is to convert `list2` to a `HashSet<int>` prior to the `Contains` call. This allows for faster lookups:

```
HashSet<int> hashSet = new HashSet<int>(list2);
List<int> result = list1.Where(i => hashSet.Contains(i)).ToList();
```

Comment: Alternatively you could use a method group `var result = list1.Where(list2.Contains).ToList();`

Comment: Note that if the lists are very big, you'd be best off converting list2 to a `HashSet`, then using that `HashSet` instead of list2 in the `Contains` call. `Contains` on a HashSet is O(1), as opposed to O(N) on a `List`.

Comment: @Baldrick exactly, but I did not opt for premature optimizations as we're discussing the core concept of the intersection. The optimized result would be `O(n*m)` where `n` is the length of `list1` and `m` is the length of `list2`

Comment: @DavidHaney: That's why I +1'd your answer, and added that as a comment. Thought it was worth mentioning for future reference!

Comment: @Baldrick true enough. I've updated the answer with an optimization option as well based on your feedback!

Comment: @DavidHaney: Nice! A preferable approach to building a decent answer than 'fastest finger first'. :)

Comment: @Baldrick I must admit I sometimes fall victim to the "fastest finger first" answer as well. ;)